# distribution min

Tags: probability-distributions

I have random values $X,Y$ and

$f(x,y) = 2x+4y$  , where $0\le x\le 1$ , $0 \le y \le 1-x$

How to calculate distribution of

$Z = \min(X,Y)$ ?

As I calculated, $X$ and $Y$ are dependent, because

$f(x) \cdot f(y) \neq f(x,y)$

Comment: [[Psst! Hey, look at this!](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :) ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $X\geqslant0$, $Y\geqslant0$ and $X+Y\leqslant1$ almost surely hence $0\leqslant Z\leqslant1/2$ almost surely. For every $z$ in $(0,1/2)$, $[Z\geqslant z]=[X\geqslant z,Y\geqslant z]$ is
$$
[X\geqslant z,1-X\geqslant Y\geqslant z]=[1-z\geqslant X\geqslant z,1-X\geqslant Y\geqslant z],
$$ 
hence
$$
P(Z\geqslant z)=\int_z^{1-z}\int_z^{1-x}f(x,y)\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx.
$$
Considering that you are able to compute the RHS as $G(z)$, the PDF $g$ of $Z$ is such that $g(z)=-G'(z)$ on $0\lt z\lt1/2$. Unless I am mistaken, and to let you check your computations, let me mention that one gets
$$
g(z)=3(1-4z^2)\,\mathbf 1_{0\lt z\lt1/2}.
$$

Comment: Why you use P(Z >= z) instad of P(Z < z) ? I didn't understand what you wrote about RHS and PDF, because I'm not familiar with this

Comment: Events (Z>z) are easier to deal with than (Z<z) when Z is a minimum (to see why, read the post). RHS = right hand side. PDF = probability density function.

Comment: ok thank you. When z isn't in range (0; 1/2) g(z) = 0, right ?